# mongoskin db.collection.find().toArray() don't work in os x

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native, mongoskin

why this code work well in linux (ubuntu12.04). don't work in os x 10.8/9 (node version, mongoskin version is the some)

```
var mongo = require('mongoskin');

exports.test = function(req, res) {
  var db = mongo.db('localhost:27017/btc', {safe: false});
  db.collection('user').find({}).toArray(function(err, results){
    console.log(results)
    res.json(200, {'flag': true});
  });
}
```

in os platform. it take error.

```
/Users/apple/code/btc/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:242
throw message;      
      ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
  at commandHandler      /Users/apple/code/btc/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:706:16)
  at /Users/apple/code/btc/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1801:9
  at Server.Base._callHandler (/Users/apple/code/btc/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:442:41)
  at /Users/apple/code/btc/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:485:18
  at MongoReply.parseBody (/Users/apple/code/btc/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:68:5)
  at null.<anonymous> (/Users/apple/code/btc/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:443:20)
  at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
  at null.<anonymous> (/Users/apple/code/btc/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:191:13)
  at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
  at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/apple/code/btc/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:418:22)
```

Comment: Can you add the version of MongoDB and mongoskin you are using.
Also, having your full script and how you call it from the command line could help.

Comment: @DanielCoupal mongoskin version is "0.6.0" , MongoDB version is v2.4.8

Comment: Can you post the full script, including the call to export.test() and your command line call?
I am not familiar with 'mongoskin'.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mongoskin = require('mongoskin');
var url = 'localhost:27017/btc';
db = mongoskin.db(url, {safe: false});
db.bind('user', {});
db.user.find({}).toArray(function(err, results){
  console.log(results);
})
```